# How to create web client application with nodejs and npm like angularjs tutorial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs, npm also angularjs.
I have read and tried the angularjs tutorial project hosted on https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git,
  which for me is really exciting because it shows how easy to maintain the modules with bower, testing with jasmine and karma and perform e2e with protractor  using npm command,
my question is, if I want to create project something like that, what I must do step by step? Is there any tutorial for creating project setup like that with npm and nodejs, not limited with angularjs but maybe just plain html CSS javascript or maybe with jquery.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First install [node](https://nodejs.org/download/)
- then install [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) with `npm install -g yo`
- then install the desired yeoman generators

  - for basic web app  `npm install -g generator-webapp`
  - for angular `npm install -g generator-angular`
- then run the installer generator.

  - exemple with webapp : `yo webapp`
- or with angular : `yo angular`

I suggest you to read the [yeoman getting started page](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html)